# Java scanner of limited input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Write a Java program that reads three numbers per line from the standard
input and up to a maximum of 1000 lines.

I could not found the limit of scanner.Is there anyone to help me,please?

Comment: i´d say you will need a loop.

Comment: show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit as such. You have to do it manually

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
        // Do your job
        count++;
        if(count == 100 )
            break;
    }
```